# Installing Dlib gets into error requseting cmake.. and c++

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

I have installed cmake and configured via env and after that too dlib wont install i need dlib because i want to install face-recagation complete logs are here

```
\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\rohit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c843pmpx\dlib_fdc8123b6a054d40aa6908544fdd7ce4\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Python310\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Python310\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 568, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Python310\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python310\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Python310\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\rohit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c843pmpx\dlib_fdc8123b6a054d40aa6908544fdd7ce4\setup.py", line 134, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\rohit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c843pmpx\dlib_fdc8123b6a054d40aa6908544fdd7ce4\setup.py", line 174, in build_extension
        subproc
      File "C:\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rohit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c843pmpx\\dlib_fdc8123b6a054d40aa6908544fdd7ce4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rohit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c843pmpx\\dlib_fdc8123b6a054d40aa6908544fdd7ce4\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\rohit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0xikgbnf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Python310\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

It requires more than cmake

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 14.0 + solves the issue